# ¿Por que no me funciona el label for ? HTML

Tags: html, css3, input, label

Hola estoy haciendo una seleccion de colores con el input radio y quiero q seleccione solo un color, lo quiero hacer con html por que vi q se puede realizar con el label for pero a mi no me funciona , cuando elijo un color y despues otro selecciona a todos, no puedo encontrar mi error:

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    
}

.opciones-color input , .opciones-color label{
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

input[type=radio]{

  cursor: pointer;

}

label{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#negro {

 background: black;

}
 #amarillo{
  background:  yellow;

}

 #rojo {
 background:  red;
 }

 #azul{
 background:  blue;}

  #verde{
    background:  green;
  }




.opciones-color input[type="radio"] + label {
    position: relative;
    margin-rigth: 10px; 
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
      
</head>
<body>

     <div class="opciones-color"> 

                <input type="radio" class="negro color" name="c-negro" > 
                <label for="c-negro"  id="negro"></label> 

                <input type="radio"  class="amarillo color" name="c-amarillo"> 
                <label for="c-amarillo" id="amarillo"></label> 

                <input type="radio"  class="rojo color" name="c-rojo"> 
                <label for="c-rojo"  id="rojo"></label> 

                <input type="radio"  class="azul color" name="c-azul">
                <label for="c-azul"  id="azul"></label>
        
                <input type="radio" class="verde color" name="c-verde">
                <label for="c-verde"  id="verde"></label>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Simple, usa el mismo name para todos, agrega un id para cada uno y su propio value (valor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por que para agrupar RadioButtons, se usa el name,
Mientras que para el label for, se relaciona con el id...

```css
.boton{
  border: 2px dotted red;
  height: 25px;
}

.rb{
 border: 2px dotted blue;
 margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<input class="rb" type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male">
  <label class="boton" for="male">Hombre</label><br>
  <input class="rb" type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">
  <label class="boton" for="female">Mujer</label><br>
```

Por lo que tu codigo debería quedar del siguiente modo:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

}

.opciones-color input,
.opciones-color label {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

input[type=radio] {

  cursor: pointer;

}

label {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#negro {

  background: black;

}

#amarillo {
  background: yellow;

}

#rojo {
  background: red;
}

#azul {
  background: blue;
}

#verde {
  background: green;
}




.opciones-color input[type="radio"]+label {
  position: relative;
  margin-rigth: 10px;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="opciones-color">

      <input type="radio" class="negro color" name="colores" id="c-negro">
      <label for="c-negro" id="negro"></label>

      <input type="radio" class="amarillo color" name="colores" id="c-amarillo">
      <label for="c-amarillo" id="amarillo"></label>

      <input type="radio" class="rojo color" name="colores" id="c-rojo">
      <label for="c-rojo" id="rojo"></label>

      <input type="radio" class="azul color" name="colores" id="c-azul">
      <label for="c-azul" id="azul"></label>

      <input type="radio" class="verde color" name="colores" id="c-verde">
      <label for="c-verde" id="verde"></label>

    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ya entendi y funciona :D , Saludos!